# Is this proof about functions on the product topology correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\{X_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ and $\{Y_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be sets of topological spaces and $f_\lambda : X_\lambda\to Y_\lambda$ be maps. I want to show that if $X = \prod X_\lambda$ and $Y = \prod_\lambda Y_\lambda$ with the product topology and  $f : X\to Y$ defined by

$$(f(x))_\lambda = f_\lambda(x_\lambda) $$

is continuous if and only if all $f_\lambda$ are continuous.

My proof is as follows: we first recognize that

$$f(x)_\lambda = f_\lambda \circ \pi_\lambda(x)$$

Thus we have for each $\lambda$:

$$\pi_\lambda^Y \circ f = f_\lambda \circ \pi_\lambda^X$$

Now we remember that each projection map $\pi_\lambda^X,\pi_\lambda^Y$ is a quotient map. In that case we first suppose $f$ is continuous, hence since $\pi_\lambda^Y$ is continuous, $\pi_\lambda^Y\circ f$ is continuous.

Since then $f_\lambda \circ \pi_\lambda^X$ is a continuous map and $\pi_\lambda^X$ is a quotient map for all $\lambda$, it follows $f_\lambda$ is a continuous map from the properties of a quotient map.

On the other hand, suppose $f_\lambda$ is continuous, then $\pi_\lambda^Y\circ f$ is continuous. Now obviously $f$ is continuous, because if $(x_\alpha)$ is a net on $X$ converging to $X$ the net $((f(x_\alpha))$ converges to $f(x)$ if and only if $(\pi_\lambda^Y\circ f(x_\alpha))$ converges to $\pi_\lambda^Y \circ f(x)$. But since $\pi_\lambda^Y\circ f$ is continuous, it does happen that $(\pi_\lambda^Y\circ f(x_\alpha))$ converges to $\pi_\lambda^Y(f(x))$ and hence $f$ is continuous.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Is $X$ the product of the $X_\lambda$ and $Y$ the product of the $Y_\lambda$, with the product topology?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to properly define it on the question. I've added this information now.

Comment: You mislabelled the projections, as written you have $\pi_\lambda^X \colon Y \to Y_\lambda$. Also you need to demand the products be nonempty.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean we need to demand the products are non-empty? Doesn't it follow from axiom of choice?

Comment: @Wore We don't have a condition that $X_\lambda \neq \varnothing$. If any factor is empty, the whole product is.

Comment: @DanielFischer, indeed I had mislabelled them, it should be $\pi_\lambda^X : X\to X_\lambda$ and $\pi_\lambda^Y : Y\to Y_\lambda$ I've corrected it. So, apart from this notation issue, and the fact that we need to suppose $X_\lambda\neq \emptyset$ for all $\lambda$, is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes. Although I find it inconsistent that in the first part you use a universal property (for quotient maps), and in the second part you don't and instead introduce a net. By definition of the product topology, $g \colon Z \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_\lambda^Y \circ g$ is continuous for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$.